# Custom Post Type Loop: grouped titles in columns of 4 with content for those 4 posts directly below them in columns of 1

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, bootstrap-4

I’m trying to do a PHP loop that will output the following for a custom post type:

```
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 1</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 2</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 3</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 1</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 2</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 3</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 5</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 6</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 7</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 8</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 5</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 6</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 7</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 8</div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, this is a bootstrap accordion, where the titles are in 4 columns, but when the accordion collapses, it collapses into full-width columns that will push the rows below it down.

I also have to keep in mind responsive, so that when it goes to the col-md size the output will change to:

```
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 1</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 2</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 1</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 3</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 3</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 5</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 6</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 5</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 6</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 7</div>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 8</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 7</div>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 8</div>
</div>
```

And then, when it goes to the col-sm size, it changes to:

```
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 1</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 1</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 2</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 3</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 3</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 4</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 5</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 5</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 6</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 6</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 7</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 7</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3”>Custom Post Title 8</div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class=“col-12”>Custom Post Content 8</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I’ve tried everything and I have an idea of what I’m trying to do, but I can’t get it right. I’ve tried to group/chunk them into groups of 4, nested loops, counts, etc.
[image: img]

Comment: I don't think a PHP loop will accomplish what you're trying to do since it generates static markup and you need your markup to be fluid based on user agent.

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I can think of 3 options. 1st, you can print the content three times using three separate PHP loops and use some simpler JS and CSS to display the appropriate block based on viewport (e.g. wrapping each content block in a div with special class that has conditional visibility based on viewport width). Second, you can print the content once using a single PHP loop and use some complicated JS to re-arrange the markup based on viewport. Third you can re-design your target markup so it can be printed with PHP in a single loop but re-arranged to fit different viewports via more complex CSS